# Is pyephem/libastro returning ICRS coordinates?

Tags: pyephem

I was unable to find the reference system that pyephem uses. I assume it is ICRS (International Celestial Reference System), is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C library that PyEphem wraps was written in the 1990s, before the creation of the ICRS reference system, and therefore PyEphem only knows about the traditional equatorial coordinate system. The most details about the coordinate systems are at the page:

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/coordinates.html

You can see that equatorial coordinates created manually, as with other coordinates returned by the API, follow the rule that “If you do not specify an epoch, then J2000 is assumed.” So there is no concept within PyEphem of stepping *outside* all epoch-based coordinate systems and using an epoch-neutral system like ICRS instead.

Comment: Just to clarify further, by "traditional", do you mean the earth-centered inertial system (ECI, also GEI)?

Comment: Or otherwise... to which coordinate class of [astropysics](http://pythonhosted.org/Astropysics/coremods/coords.html) does it correspond?

Comment: My guess would be that PyEphem coordinates are what astropysics represents with its `EquatorialCoordinatesEquinox` class.